# Re-using Javascript snippets in an ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a few jQuery plugins in various views on my site. In some cases, the plugins are initialized within an external javascript on page load using document.ready. In other cases, the initialization is done within the callback fn of another plugin, or maybe after an ajax call reloads a partial view.

I find that I'm copy-pasting the same plugin initialization snippet in more than one place depending on how/where it needs to be initialized.

To illustrate this with an example:

Case 1: [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) which uses a [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) which in turn uses the [expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) plugin

```
$(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({  // calendar
   .. snip ..
      eventRender: function (calEvent, element) { // render qtip on eventRender
            element.qtip({
            ...snip...
                events: {
                    ....snip....
                    render: function () {// initialize expander on callback
                        // SNIPPET start
                        $('div.expandable').expander({
                            expandPrefix: '',
                            expandText: '[...]',
                            userCollapseText: '[less]',
                            preserveWords: true,
                            widow: 4
                        });
                        // SNIPPET end
                    }
                }
```

Case 2: Partial View loaded via ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // SAME SNIPPET start
        $('div.expandable').expander({
            expandPrefix: '',
            expandText: '[...]',
            userCollapseText: '[less]',
            preserveWords: true,
            widow: 4
        });
        // SAME SNIPPET end
 });
```

Naturally, I'm not a big fan of this approach and was wondering if there are better ways to deal with this. I guess what I'm looking for is a "partial view" concept, but for javascript within a .NET MVC3 Razor site. The idea being to have the $('div.expandable') snippet in a common location and included where ever its needed.

Any ideas/suggestions that might work with both external js files as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What I usually do is create [helper objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) for my javascript snippets. [See this for a "tutorial".](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

What you do is create file called JavascriptHelper.cshtml in your app_code folder, and pretty add to it:

**basically:**

```
@helper qTipRender()
{
    // SNIPPET start
    $('div.expandable').expander({
        expandPrefix: '',
        expandText: '[...]',
        userCollapseText: '[less]',
        preserveWords: true,
        widow: 4
    });
    // SNIPPET end
}
```

Then inside your view:

```
render: function () {
    @JavascriptHelper.qTipRender();
}
```

**With parameters:**

what you can also do is add parameters:

```
@helper qTipRender(bool preserveWords)
{
    // SNIPPET start
    $('div.expandable').expander({
        expandPrefix: '',
        expandText: '[...]',
        userCollapseText: '[less]',
        preserveWords: @preserveWords,
        widow: 4
    });
    // SNIPPET end
}
```

Then inside your view:

```
render: function () {
    @JavascriptHelper.qTipRender(true);
}
```

makes it very easy to maintain lots of javascript snippits, even if their parameters differ a little.

Comment: sorry, I jumped the gun - your answer is spot on, but wouldn't work for external js files, since js wouldn't understand the @JavascriptHelper bit. Guess the only way might be a js-only solution (if there is one)

Comment: what do you mean by external js files? Like including jquery.expander.js and such? Because normally besides the initialization you don't go messing around in the external libraries right?

Comment: I mean where the javascript call to @JavascriptHelper helper methods is actually in an external file. So say I have my own calendar.js file which initializes the fullcalendar, the qtip and the expander and this .js is included in the view via a RenderSection